# Get atributes from a parent class from child in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance

I have some Parent and Clild class in Python 3 with some atributes, one of these atributes is the sum between the other.

Parent Class:

```
class Parent:
    ATRIBUTE1 = 'dad'
    ATRIBUTE2 = ' good'
    ATRIBUTE3 = ATRIBUTE1 + ATRIBUTE2
```

Child Class:

```
class Child(Parent):
    ATRIBUTE1 = 'son'
    ATRIBUTE2 = ' bad'
```

I just want inherit the ATRIBUTE3 in the Child Class with the same properties.

Expected output:

```
>> parent.ATRIBUTE3
'dad good'

>> child.ATRIBUTE3
'son bad'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a property.

```
class Parent:
    ATRIBUTE1 = 'dad'
    ATRIBUTE2 = ' good'

    @property
    def attribute3(self):
        return self.ATRIBUTE1 + self.ATRIBUTE2
```

Now `parent.attribute3` and `child.attribute3` will give you the result you want.

Comment: But it could NOT be accessed as a class variable i.e as `Child.attribute3`

Answer (score 1):

`ATTRIBUTE3` is evaluated at class creation time, and not recalculated on every access. Therefore you inherit parent's value, not formula.

If you wish attribute value recalculated on every access you can use `@property`:

```
class Parent:
    ATRIBUTE1 = 'dad'
    ATRIBUTE2 = ' good'

    @property
    def ATRIBUTE3(self):
        return self.ATRIBUTE1 + self.ATRIBUTE2
```

And you can access it the same way as before (though read only):

```
print(child.ATTRIBUTE3)
```